# 'tensorflowjs_converter' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflowjs-converter

I have installed tensorflow 2.5.0 in python 3.8. I have also successfully installed tensorflowjs. But when I run this command

```
command = "tensorflowjs_converter --input_format=tf_saved_model --output_node_names='detection_boxes,detection_classes,detection_features,detection_multiclass_scores,detection_scores,num_detections,raw_detection_boxes,raw_detection_scores' --output_format=tfjs_graph_model --signature_name=serving_default {} {}".format(os.path.join(paths['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'saved_model'), paths['TFJS_PATH'])

!{command}
```

I got this error

```
    'tensorflowjs_converter' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: What is the output when you run `tensorflowjs_converter --version` ? If you still get the same error then the problem is with the `tensorflowjs` installation.

Answer (score 2):

I unistalled tenserflowjs and again installed it . It worked successfully.

```
!pip uninstall tensorflowjs
!pip install tensorflowjs
```